# Was the Sarangapani temple ever converted from Thenkalai to Vadakalai?

Tags: temple, history, sri-vaishnava, vadakalai, thenkalai

The conversion of the great Kanchi temple from Thenkalai to Vadakalai is a well known fact (lot of documentation in the court cases). Can somebody provide historic records (court records etc) or archival evidence regarding the conversion (*if ever converted*) of the Aaravumudan temple in Kumbakonsm (Thirukudanthai), commonly known as the Sarangapani temple?

Comment: Curious why it is called sarangapani. Sarangapani is Shiva. zArGgapAni is vishnu. Is it just people's inability to pronounce it correctly.

Comment: @moonstar2001, what does Sarangapani mean ?

Comment: @ram deer. Lord Shiva holds the head of  deer in one hand and hence he is saaranga pANi.

Comment: @moonstar2001 ok yeah, vishnu dhanush is शार्ङ्ग Shaarnga, while shiva deer is सारङ्ग Saaranga.. since in tamil there is only one ச for both, it's possible they mix it up. generally though, sarangapani is common name among iyengars.

Comment: @ram limitation of the native language and its influence on the people who speak it as I guessed.